# Mobile Internet Problem

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, networkmanager

I am using mobile dial up on ubuntu.

However, SOMETIMES even though I am connected to the ISP, I do not have any entries in /etc/resolv.conf. I often restart network-manager or networking hoping it will change but normally it doesn't do any good. and by connected I mean I can see that the network notification icon has switched to a few bars indicating connectivity).

Anyone know a good solution around this?

Answer (score 1):

Make your own /etc/resolv.conf with publicly accessible DNS servers.  For example, you could create a file /etc/resolv.conf.opendns with contents

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

and then

```
cp /etc/resolv.conf.opendns /etc/resolv.conf
```

to have your system use the OpenDNS servers.  Of course, this doesn't tell you why the /etc/resolv.conf file is empty, but it should enable your machine to use DNS to resolve names.